# What was the exact triple point of water in the pre-1954 definition of Celsius and in the post-2019 definition of Celsius?

Tags: temperature, definition, si-units, metrology

1. 

In 1954 the definition of Celsius was changed in terms of absolute zero and the triple point of water. And the triple point was chosen to be exactly 0.01C. Since there is no physical reason for the triple point to be exactly at that point, this was obviously rounded and has inevitably led to a slight shift and/or skew in the temperature scale.
My question is how much was this change? And how precisely can we know this? I assume it was close to the tolerance of what we could measure (for instance 0.011C± 0.005C)

For example. Let's say the triple point was 0.011 pre-1954C and it was rounded to 0.01 1954C, this would mean a shift of -0.001 pre-1954C.

Scientists had to measure the tripple point at some point using prior to 1954 so I assume they documented their measurements and the motivation for choosing 0.01C. I would like to know where I can find such documented measurements.

2)
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/506002
"On May 20 [2019], the definition of the Kelvin scale is to be changed so that the Boltzmann constant will be defined to be 1.380649×10−23 J⋅K−1. After this date it is possible that more precise measurements than have previously been done will find that the triple point of water is not at exactly 0.01 C"

I wonder if such measurements have been conducted and what the result were.
For example. Let's say the triple point was 0.01 pre-2019C and it was calculated to be 0.0101 post-2019C (from measuring the Boltzmann constant), this would mean a shift of +0.0001 pre-2019C. But I assume these changes are much smaller since the constants used have many significant digits. So this is less relevant to my question, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the currently accepted value for the triple point temperature is still 273.16 Kelvin. Given this was the old definition, and that the new definition in terms of the Bolztmann constant was both defined in order not to change this value, and to a precision of 6 significant figures, you can be assured that as long as the measurement had no glaring systematic errors, both the pre-1954 value and the post-2019 value for the triple point temperature is 273.16 ± 0.001.

Comment: That answers the second part of my question. Thank you. But I still like to know the first part of the question. I'm not asking about Kelvin. I'm asking about the triple point measurements in pre-1954 Celsius.

Comment: The Kelvin and Celsius units are defined to be the same magnitude, so it doesn't matter which we use. When considering precision of measurements it is important to use an absolute scale like Kelvin over an offset one like Celsius. 

As to the first part of your question, you already answered it in your question, "0.011C± 0.005C". The triple point temperature is always the same, the only thing that is changing is the measured magnitude of the unit. Before 1954 the definitions for Celsius were not precise enough to even consider things with a precision of milliCelsius, so the answer is 0.01 C.

Comment: Science is based on skepticism. Scientists must have motivated their decision. I'd like to see the reports. I can't imagine these reports have been destroyed.

Comment: I fail to see how science being based on skepticism has anything to do with it, and I'm not sure what decision was even made that you are referring to. I can't imagine a mundane measurement like this would have been published to a journal pre-1954. I couldn't find anything of the sort at least. What you're looking for probably only exists in some book of figures in a dusty research library somewhere, and if I had to guess what you'll find is a value of 0.01 C, that's the precision they had at the time.